# I need to know how to structure my WordPress theme

Tags: theme-development

I am a little bit confused about how my WordPress theme files will look like

I've already a website with a purpose to review Movies and Tv Shows

And it's a regular site, the website directory looks like this

[image]
Now with WordPress, I see things have a different behavior

What I need to know is how to structure my pages well

- Movies: that will show the latest added Movies
- Shows: that will show the latest TV Shows added
- Movie: that will show the specific movie info
- Show: that will show the specific show info
- Season: that will show the specific season info and links to its episodes
- Episode: hat will show the specific episode info

I've already used CPTUI to create custom post types but I had a rough night trying to know how to apply CSS to my pages and what HTML should go in each custom post type

I need an answer to put my mind at ease because the reason I am migrating to WordPress is that the latest version of my website was terrible and had a lot of problems so I need to be sure that there will be no more critical mistakes

Thank you guys for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, You should create different [page template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) for each page.

While developing a new Wordpress theme just go through [wordpress file structure](http://aming.info/wordpress-themes-file-structure)

Also this site will helps you to generate ready made [theme file structure](http://underscores.me).

Now, as per your structure...

1) **Movies**: that will show the latest added Movies - that will be your `page template` that will display all the movies stored in the Moives [`Custom post types`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

2) **Movie**: that will show the specific movie info - that will be a [detail page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates) of movies `custom post type`. Your file name must be `single-{post_type }.php`; so in your case it should be `single-movies.php` ( the name you have registered in your custom post type. )

3) **Season**: that will show the specific season info and links to its episodes ; 
**Episode**: that will show the specific episode info - it will be your movies [`custom_taxonomy`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)